# Tint Color of Appstore TopBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uicolor, tint

I like to use the same tint color that apple uses for its iOS6 Appstore top bar.
[image]

But I can't manage to find out the right color. I tried a lot of colors but none of them was right.

Does anybody have a clue.

Comment: use `DigitalColor Meter` app on your mac, you can see it is not one color they use gradient that goes from top 81,81,81 to bottom 26,26,26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do this by giving black as the navigation bar's tint color.(iOS5+ apps)**

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```